# String Parsing with repitive delimiter

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have the following string:

> $Categories:BY
>   COLOR:Spice$Categories:CATEGORIES:Botanical$Categories:CATEGORIES:Botanical:Leaves$Sources:adl-bdc2012:vol1:PUBLISHED-NON-150:KOETSIER,ALBERT$Categories:CATEGORIES:Seasonal / Holiday

I would like to parse this string and want result to be:

> Spice, Botanical, Leaves, KOETSIER, ALBERT, Seasonal/Holiday

I was thinking `Substring` but seems it would get too convoluted. What is a better approach?

Comment: First show an approach... (Hint - `Split`)

Answer (score 3):

I would use split(string), splitting it by '$' and then by ':' just like this

```
yourLongString.Split('$').Select(v => v.Split(':')).ToArray();
```

it will give you an array of string arrays, I think it can help you to format the string as you want, you can see the result in the following picture:

[image: Quickwatch of yourLongString variable]

Answer (score 0):

This is also another way to solve it:
You split by `$` character, then you by pass any empty spaces, then you take sub string than index end with `:` colon and return it as list of string or array.

```
var xs = str.Split('$')
    .Where(p => p != "")
    .Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1))
    .ToList();
```

To print the results:

```
xs.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output

```
Spice
Botanical
Leaves
KOETSIER, ALBERT
Seasonal / Holiday
```

Then you can decoreated with comma in one line.